# Type III von Neumann algebra generated by one operator

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Is it possible to *explicitly* construct the Hilbert space $H$ and operator $T \in B(H)$ such that the von Neumann it generates is type $III$ factor? I would like to see an example.

Comment: Have you tried working through the argument in http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1969-75-01/S0002-9904-1969-12157-9/home.html ?

Comment: Olsen and Zame provide an explicit generator of the CAR algebra in http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1976-215-00/S0002-9947-1976-0388114-7/S0002-9947-1976-0388114-7.pdf  Then pick a state (Powers '67 Annals) on the CAR algebra that generates a Type III factor.